# Does the Soul Forge cost something (except time)?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

As the title says, does the use of the [Soul Forge](http://heroes-6-conflux.uk.ubi.com/soulforge) in the Conflux web application cost something except time?

It takes time to upgrade a Dynasty Weapon, and it doesn't consume my Dynasty points. So I don't understand what's the catch?

Comment: Woah, I never knew that existed.

Comment: Hehe, I found it by chance while browsing http://www.celestialheavens.com It would be good to have it mentioned IN the game.

Comment: I used it. It looks like the only downside is that for the higher levels you have to leave your computer on for 24 hours or more, but obviously that is not conclusive.

Comment: I take that back. I tried closing the tab and reopening, and it appeared to continue when the tab was not open.

Comment: Yes, it's a web app written in ASP.NET, it runs on the server not on your browser. So you can turn off your computer while it "cooks".

Comment: @Mentoliptus It does run on the server, and effectively consumes only time, but you'll have to tell me where you know from that it's ASP !

Comment: @Gimiz - off-topic, but generally if the pages have an .aspx extension, then the site is written in ASP.NET.

Comment: @JasonBerkan: you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that it costs is time.  The "catch", as you put it, is that they are getting you to log in to their website regularly, where they can serve you ads or other content that they want you to see.